# Comando SQL no MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sintaxe

Estou criando um DBA e preciso fazer um **CHECK** em um índice da minha tabela `produto`, mas estou utilizando o MySQL e estou tendo um problema com a sintaxe.

Segue o exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE produto(
Cod_produto int primary key not null,
nome_produto varchar(50) NOT NULL,
descricao text, 
cod_tipoProduto int  not null,
valor_Compra decimal (12,3) not null,
valor_Venda decimal (12,3) not null,
CONSTRAINT valorDeVenda CHECK  valor_Venda IN (valor_Venda>= 0),
CONSTRAINT valorDeCompra CHECK valor_Compra IN (valor_Compra>=0)

);
```

Erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual o problema que você está tendo? Qual erro está sendo retornado? Seja mais específico.

Comment: Atualizei o erro, com uma Imagem para ser mais específico

Answer (score 2):

O erro está onde você monta o ***[CHECK](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp)***, não precisa do `valor_Venda IN`:

```
CREATE TABLE produto(
  Cod_produto int primary key not null,
  nome_produto varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  descricao text, 
  cod_tipoProduto int  not null,
  valor_Compra decimal (12,3) not null,
  valor_Venda decimal (12,3) not null,
  CONSTRAINT CHK_valorDeVenda CHECK (valor_Venda>= 0),
  CONSTRAINT CHK_valorDeCompra CHECK (valor_Compra>=0)
);
```

Comment: Então ja tentei desta maneira e esta dando os mesmos Erros, da Imagem  que está na pergunta.

Comment: tentou criar direto sem adicionar um nome? tipo `valor_Venda decimal (12,3) not null, CHECK (valor_Venda >= 0)`

Comment: Sim, dei uma olhada na documentação e no W3school  com os exemplos .Fiz já os seguintes Teste. valor_Venda decimal (12,3) not null, CHECK (valor_Venda >= 0)  , valor_Venda decimal CHECK(valor_venda>=0) e a criação de constraint que ainda continua com o mesmo erro